# How to connect to MySQL using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have been working on a form that uses PHP to send e-mails to my account. To save room and de-clutter my mailbox account I am now trying to now use the same PHP to send the info to a MySQL server to log the data. The code I have been trying to make work keeps giving the same error of:

> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future

Here is the PHP code that I am currently trying to use:

```
$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$dbname = 'on-boarding';
mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($dbname);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO  new_employees ('OnBoardedBy', 'EmployeeName', 'HomePhone') VALUES ('$onboarded_by','$employee_name','$home_phone')");
```

Comment: Check out the mysqli functions, or PDO

Comment: Sidenote: Remove the quotes in `('OnBoardedBy', 'EmployeeName', 'HomePhone')` or use backticks `\``

Comment: Fred -ii- removing the quotes solved the problem thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use PDO or MySQLi. I'd recommend directly to use PDO and not MySQLi. PDO has a better integration of Prepared Statements. Do it like this:

```
try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".$host.";dbname=".$db.";charset=utf8", $user, $password);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die("Unable to connect. Error: ".$e->getMessage());
}

$link = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO  new_employees (`OnBoardedBy`, `EmployeeName`, `HomePhone`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$link->bindvalue(1, $onboarded_by);
$link->bindvalue(2, $employee_name);
$link->bindvalue(3, $home_phone);
$link->execute();
$row = $link->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

edit: Let me add an example for a prepared query.

Comment: Sidenote: The use of PDO is not a safeguard against SQL injection; not on its own that is. The use of [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) does.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is not going to support the MySQL extension for much longer anymore. It is recommend to use MySQLi or PDO.

```
$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$dbname = 'on-boarding';

$link = mysqli_connect('$host', '$username', '$password', '$dbname');
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO  new_employees (`OnBoardedBy`, `EmployeeName`, `HomePhone`) VALUES ('$onboarded_by','$employee_name','$home_phone')");
```

Prepared statements are much safer and avoid the risk of sql injection: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: I understand what you were trying to say, but it's a little misleading. You may want to mention that it's the _MySQL_ extension that won't be supported much longer. Your first sentence makes it seem like PHP will not support _MySQL_ as a database much longer. It's just the extension that will be removed.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ok, I forgot the $link in the mysqli query. Thanks for stating

Comment: You forgot a lot more than just the $link ,haha.

Comment: It's not what I meant. [`See my comment here`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25024438/how-to-connect-to-mysql-using-php/25024545#comment38917128_25024438) regarding OP's code.

Comment: You also forgot a starting double quote, and ending semi-colon.

Comment: Plus, [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) are better/safer. This is open to SQL injection; as a sidenote ;)