# apostrophe not send to database

Tags: php, html, mysql

i need your help. today i saw that if i put `'`(apostrophe) in some words then this text will not send to database. I tride to delete `htmlentites` or `htmlspecialchars` but not helped. please help me to fix this problem. thanks.
hier is profile.php

```
<?php
if(logged_in() === true){
    if(empty($_POST['status']) === false && empty($_POST['user_status']) === false){
        $status_data = array(
            'body' => $_POST['status'],
            'added_by' =>$user_data['username'],
            'date_added' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'user_posted_to' =>  $_GET['username'],
            'user_id' => $user_data['user_id']
        );
        update_status($id, $status_data, $user_id);
    }
?>
<form class="forma" action="<? echo $username; ?>" method="post" accept-charset="utf8">
    <div class="field">

        <label for="Status" style="color: #7f7f7f; font-family: Cambria, Hoefler Text, Liberation Serif, Times, Times New Roman, serif;"></label>
        <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="status" placeholder="say something" id="status_area" charset="UTF-8" style=".value:black;"></textarea>
        <div class='fild_bottom'>
            <input name="user_status" type="submit" value="Post" id="button">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is `function.php`:

```
function update_status($id, $status_data, $user_id){
    $query = @mysql_query('set character_set_results = "utf8"');
    $user_id = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = $user_id");

    array_walk($status_data, 'array_sanitize');

    $fields  = '`' . implode('`,`', array_keys($status_data)) . '`';
    $bank ='\'' . implode('\', \'', $status_data) . '\'';

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `status` ($fields) VALUES ($bank)");
}
function array_sanitize($item){
    $item = htmlentities(strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($item)));
}

function sanitize($data){
    return htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($data)));
}
```

Comment: Your `sanitize` functions are completely wrong.  You should only escape as the format you're actually concatenating into.

Comment: why is this tagged java?

Comment: Take a look at addslashes and stripslashes

Comment: if i change `htmlspechialchars` to `htmlentites` will it work? @SLaks

Comment: @BackSlash that was wrong sorry

Comment: Btw your code is vulnerable to sql injections. Try PDO or mysqli, otherwise you are going to be a victim of some kind of maliciois bots/users.

Comment: @user3722203: No; that will be equally wrong.  You need to understand what those functions do.

Comment: i tride to change to pdo but it was for me very hard. ((( @HddnTHA

Comment: but in this situation i didn't used `sanatize`. i used `just array_sanatize`

Comment: For PDO use the example of my answer from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25024438/how-to-connect-to-mysql-using-php/25024618#25024618

Comment: @CharlotteDunois thank you. thats awasome. i will try to change to PDO. But i have 1 quastion. what is differens between PDO and OOP? i thought they are same. or?

Comment: PDO and OOP are two pair of shoes. OOP is Object-oriented programming, while PDO is PHP Data Objects. They have nothing to do with each other. http://ch1.php.net/manual/en/oop5.intro.php http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php

Comment: ok. I understand. thanks. and can you help in this code? )) @CharlotteDunois

Answer (score 2):

Please change your code to PDO. For an example, I'm refering to this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25024438/how-to-connect-to-mysql-using-php/25024618#25024618)

Change your function update_status to this (it's implied you've already made an db connection (object in $db)):

```
/* $user_id is unused, you should think about removing it */
function update_status($id, $status_data, $user_id) {
    global $db;

    $link = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `status` (`body`, `added_by`, `date_added`, `user_posted_to`, `user_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $link->bindvalue(1, $status_data['body']);
    $link->bindvalue(2, $status_data['added_by']);
    $link->bindvalue(3, $status_data['date_added']);
    $link->bindvalue(4, $status_data['user_posted_to']);
    $link->bindvalue(5, $status_data['user_id']);
    $link->execute();
}
```

And remove the functions array_sanitize() and sanitize(), you won't need them anymore (Thanks to PDO and Prepared Statements). Also there is no need to use array_keys on the $status_data array, if the keys are always the same and known.

I don't know why you're selecting the user_id again in this function, since you're already getting it in $status_data.

edit: Throw this in a central file (you can either set the variables before `try {` or replace them with the correct values):

```
try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".$host.";dbname=".$db.";charset=utf8", $user, $password);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false); //Stops emulating Prepared Statements
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die("Unable to connect. Error: ".$e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: i have chaged and removed `array_sanitize` and `sanitize`. but comes fatal error.  Call to a member function prepare()

Comment: Did you create a new PDO object in order to make a connection to your database? If not, do it in a central file, which gets always included somewhere at the top (create one if you don't have one yet).

Comment: i have changed. bu become more warnings. :( i must change all codes to pdo. i think it will better. i will change all codes to pdo. can you send me your conntact email or facebook or something to conntact with you and tell you what i have changed?

Comment: ok.das ist gut. dann bis morgen. ich will alle Code zum PDO wechseln. schreibe ich dir morgen. danke für alles. das war sehr Net. und könntest du unsere Unterhaltung, die nicht zu den Themen gehört, löschen?

Comment: @user3722203: although helpers may share their private contact details if they wish, we tend to discourage question askers from actively seeking them, as it often results in the helper becoming a free private support channel. If you want to illustrate some code/changes you have made, use Github's Gists or a pasteboard - if you post it in public comments here, it means other people can comment too.