# Ban System not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, apache

I'm developing a banning sytem for my web site and all the values are correct and I get no errors on the page, but the data does not go into the table. Here's the code for database connectivity.

```
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name="PyroStudio"; // Database name
$tbl_name="banned"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
```

Here is the actual banning system itself

```
if ($_POST['post'])
{

 //get data
 $bannuser = $_POST['bannuser'];

 $TypeBan = $_POST['TypeBan'];
 $Reviewed = $_POST['Reviewed'];
 $ModNote = $_POST['ModNote'];
 $Reason = $_POST['Reason'];
 $OffenItem = $_POST['OffenItem'];
 $BanLengthMssg = $_POST['BanLengthMssg'];
 $ReleaseMssg = $_POST['ReleaseMssg'];
 $AppealMssg = $_POST['AppealMssg'];



 //Connect To The Database
 $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 mysql_select_db("PyroStudio");

 $namecheck = mysql_query("SELECT bannuser FROM $tbl_name WHERE bannuser='$bannuser'");
 $count = mysql_num_rows($namecheck);

 if($count!=0)
 {
    die("This User Is Already Banned! <a href='home.php'>[Home]</a>");
 }

 //check for existance
 if ($bannuser)
 {
    if(strlen($bannuser)>25||strlen($bannuser)<6)
        {
            echo "<b>Length Of Username Is Must Be Between 6 and 25 Characters Long!</b>";
        }
        else
            {
                $queryreg = mysql_query("
                INSERT INTO $tbl_name VALUES ('$bannuser','$TypeBan','$Reviewed','$ModNote','$Reason','$OffenItem','$BanLengthMssg','$ReleaseMssg','$AppealMssg')
                ");

                die ("<b>The Moderation Report Has Been Submitted! The User Is Now Banned!</b> <b><a href='home.php'>[Home]</a></b>");
            }
        }


}

?>
```

I've used this system before and now I dont know why it doesn't want to work. If you can help, that would be great.

Comment: Please provide us with a clue to where this code goes wrong? What debugging steps did you take?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.  Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: The first query has a SQL injection vulnerability in it.

Comment: Mouser, One part of my issue was that I had a table name wrong and then I corrected it which was the banned table. I checked my mysql connection, it was perfect, I just have no idea where this went wrong. Fred I will give that a try

Comment: You should stop using the deprecated mysql_* php extension and start using PDO. Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25024438/how-to-connect-to-mysql-using-php

Comment: @Mouser I get an error reporting back saying `Undefined index: post in /home/vol2_7/-/-/htdocs/admin/ModPanel.php on line 43` I used - to block out connections of my actual host

Comment: Are all your post vars filled. Ergo are all the post variables the same in spelling and sent?

Comment: Check with `isset();` your $_POST vars, before use in function.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to update the mqsql_connect to `mysqli_connect();` and update to `mysqli_select_db();` but for selecting the database, I get another error saying that it requires 2 parameters, the database name is one, but what's the second parameter?

Comment: Read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php and don't mix MySQL APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `mysql_query("SELECT bannuser FROM $tbl_name WHERE bannuser='$bannuser'");`

Just **don't**. This is a giant gaping security hole. Also, your code may be failing because of unescaped `$_POST` data getting into SQL statement and breaking it. Or because you had missed something with INSERT query, since you hadn't even specified a column list. If you're interested in what is the issue, check MySQL server logs for those or the result of `mysql_error()` function.

Anyway, consider the following approach:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=PyroStudio", "root", "");

$bannuser = $_POST["bannuser"];
if (strlen($bannuser) > 25 || strlen($bannuser) < 6) {
    die("Invalid username.");
}

$count = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bannuser WHERE bannuser = ?")
            ->execute(array($bannuser))
            ->fetchColumn();

if ($count > 0) {
    die("Already banned.");
}

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO bannuser (bannuser, typeban, …) VALUES (:bannuser, :typeban, …)");
$stmt->bindParam("bannuser", $bannuser);
$stmt->bindParam("typeban", $_POST["typeban"]);
…
$stmt->execute();
```

This is not a complete code (in particular, I'm too lazy to type every inserted parameter out there) but just a rough sketch I've did from memory to get you started.