# database connection. Misunderstanding of error messages

Tags: php, database, while-loop

I am receiving these error messages:

1. > Warning: PDO::__construct() expects parameter 4 to be array, string given in C:\wamp\www\MyProjects\GhislainPOO\personnages.php on line 2. There is no password required, I am wondering what it's meant by array here?
2. > Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\MyProjects\GhislainPOO\personnages.php on line 3. is $bdd not an object, although I use "new PDO"?

**PHP**

```
<?php
$bdd= new PDO ('localhost', 'POO', 'root', '');
$bdd->query( "SELECT * FROM jeux_combats");
$result = $bdd->query( "SELECT * FROM jeux_combats");


while ($donnee = $result->fetch()) {
echo '<p>'.'le personnage'.$donnee['nom'].'a une force de'.$donnee['forceperso'].'</p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/fr/pdo.construct.php

Comment: what is the type of your db? Mysql?

Comment: this line's not needed btw `$bdd->query( "SELECT * FROM jeux_combats");` that'll produce an error once you get properly connected.

Comment: Yes I am using mysql

Comment: You're using `$bdd->query()` twice too.

Comment: Oh, just for reference this SO link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25024438/how-to-connect-to-mysql-using-php/25024618#25024618

Comment: do the column(s) even exist? the right type? you need to provide DB schema.

Comment: Ya the colums exist. I am using PHP Myadmin and the table is made up of 6 columns and three entries.
I can typ the full code here: But it is displaid as a plain text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php

1. parameter: information about the database connection
2. parameter: username for the connection
3. parameter: password for the connection
4. parameter: a key=>value array of driver-specific connection options (optional)

It should be like this:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

About your second question. The error should disappear after you will fix your first problem. Anyways... You could check if `$bdd` is `null` or not if you fear that the second error could appear again even after you will fix your first problem. Something like:

```
if($bdd != null){
    if($result = $bdd->query( "SELECT * FROM jeux_combats")){
        while ($donnee = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo '<p>'.'le personnage'.$donnee['nom'].'a une force de'.$donnee['forceperso'].'</p>';
        }
    }
}
```

The whole code in your case would be:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $bdd = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

    if($bdd != null){
        if($result = $bdd->query( "SELECT * FROM jeux_combats")){
            while ($donnee = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo '<p>'.'le personnage'.$donnee['nom'].'a une force de'.$donnee['forceperso'].'</p>';
            }
        }
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: He gets the error for `$bdd is not an object` because he doesn't connect correctly to PDO. As soon as he fixes that, the error will disappear. There is no need to check if the pdo variable equals not to NULL, as long as it's after the try-catch block.

Comment: Didn't i say the same thing as you in my answer?

Comment: @ghislain2458 I don't see where you execute a query.

Comment: Try the code i provided at the bottom of my answer and let me know if it's working. It should be working.

Comment: Best to add `$bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php should there be errors. And `127.0.0.1` they may need to use `localhost`.

Comment: I tried this code, but I am still getting a message concerning the use of fetch. The fact that I am apllying it on a non-object

Comment: @CharlotteDunois when I remove the fetch part, everything works well. I am lost because I am wondering why it is condered that I am applying fetch on a non object.

Comment: @JoSmo
Here is the message
Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::fetch() in C:\wamp\www\MyProjects\GhislainPOO\personnages.php on line 13

Comment: Try now. I just copied your code before, didn't see that the fetch method was used wrong. You can read more about the use of the method here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: @ghislain2458 If it works, please mark my answer as your solution/up-vote. Thank you.